# C++ // Compare getline input to a multiple word string?

Tags: c++, string, whitespace, cin, getline

How do you compare something you get from "getline(cin, fistName);" to a string "John Doe".

Something like:

```
#include <string>

main() {
int x;
cin >> x;

string fullName;
getline(cin, fullName);
if(fullName == "John Doe")
    // some code;
}
```

Comment: Does the code you have not work to your satisfaction? What outcome do you expect, what do you observe, and how do the two differ? I don't see anything obviously wrong, besides mis-typing `getline` as `get`.

Comment: You are very right; the above code definitely does work. My problem was that I was using cin to retrieve input before using getline, which, as I know now, grabs the left over /n. So, I just used getline for everything instead!

Answer (score 1):

Once you have two strings you can use its compare function.
You can read about it here [String Compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/)

Comment: For a more suitable answer please correct your code and question.
Fix it to use the specific getline function you were talking about and elaborate which strings you had in mind. 
NULL Terminated / \n / etc.

Answer (score 0):

- change "get" to "getline" in your code, after changing your code will work fine. Instead of using "==" you can also use fullName.compare("John Deo").

Answer (score 0):

So, my problem that wasn't initially shared in the code above, was that I was using cin above getline. As I understand it now, cin 'grabs' the input and leaves the /n or 'enter' in the stream. So, just the /n registers and the user misses the opportunity to input their name as in the case above.

I resolved this by avoiding the use of cin and using getline. Also, I got around this by using cin.ignore() after using cin if it was followed by a getline.

```
main(){

string x,y;
cin >> x;
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, y);
if (x == y) {
//some code
}


}
```

Additionally, you can compare the getline value with the equals operator like in the code above.